# Virial equation of state - Taylor expansion

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I don't get how Taylor expansion over $ \frac{1}{\overline{V}} $ of Virial equation of state is caried out: $Z = \frac{P\overline{V}}{RT} $ which yields
$$ Z = 1 + \frac{B_{2V}(T)}{\overline{V}} + \frac{B_{3V}(T)}{\overline{V^2}} + ...
$$ I thought I understood calc2 Taylor expansion of form $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k $$ so maybe I was in illusion. What's is $Z$ function of? At what expansion point do we expa

Comment: I have the same question and I still don't get it.
Z = PV/RT (N=1)
And I've read that the expansion has to be when P→0, or when V→∞, so (1/V)→0.
Ok, fine, but I can't expand in a series of Taylor in terms of P or V because in this form they don't have a second (and third, fourth and so on) derivative:
Z'(P) = V/RT
Z''(P) = 0
Z'(V) = P/RT
Z''(V) = 0
From what I know, its a expansion (Maclaurin) of:
1/(1-x) which gives (1 + x + x² + x³ +...)
And I don't see a way to have PV/RT to be written in this form.
Tomorrow I'll ask my professor and I'll come back if I get a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, Z is explicitly a function of temperature.

> At what expansion point do we expand?

Can you clarify what you mean? I can state that it's common to truncate this particular expansion at the second term, so we'd have:

$$\ce Z = 1 + {B_{2V}(T)\over \overline{V}}$$

The virial coefficient in this case accounts for deviation from the ideal case by accounting for attractive and repulsive forces between the particles in the system.

Comment: I'm sorry I have badly formulated my question, but thanks for the answer. I mean if we expand around some particular point (like 0 or any other fixed value). I have reformulated my question. So Z is function of T, how do we carry out expansion over $ \frac{1}{\overline{V}}? $

Comment: Are you asking about the mechanics of the Taylor series expansion specifically?

Comment: Exactly, this is where my confusion is.

Comment: The unity term corresponds to the $k = 0$ case, and the next term (where $k = 1$) is the first derivative term (the negative sign from differentiation is incorporated in $B_{2V}$).

Answer (score 0):

The expansion in a Taylor series of is not made starting from an ideal gas equation, it's actually made from the equation for the pressure obtained from statistical mechanics, $pV = kT\ln Z$, in the grand canonical ensemble.

The derivation of the virial expansion is shown in McQuarrie (ref 1). I had misunderstood (probably you too) based on what I read in some site or videos. The ideal gas equation is obtained from the virial expansion and not the opposite.

*References*

1. McQuarrie, Donald A.. The Virial Equation of State from the Grand Partition Function, Section 12-1, p. 224, in Statistical Mechanics, ISBN 06-044366-9.